# Paramount, tantamount and ...?

Tags: vocabulary, suffixes

**Paramount**:

> more important than anything else; supreme.

**Tantamount**:

> equivalent in seriousness to; virtually the same as.

??**mount**:

> less important than anything else

What is the word that completes the trio with a matching suffix?

Comment: The Greek-derived prefix _cata-_ means "down," so maybe _catamount_?

Comment: Catamount appears to be "a medium-sized or large wild cat"

Comment: @SvenYargs: *Cata-* is nice, but both words are from Latin. And the *mons* part means *mountain*, so there is no such thing as a natural trio with "less" here.

Comment: I've got to learn how to use the universal "It's a joke" signifier properly.

Comment: How about surmount? (to surpass or to exceed) That would belong on the top of your set rather than the bottom, though (probably).

Comment: Or I've got to expand my vocabulary

Comment: @SvenY - The Greek-derived prefix *cata-* means "down," so maybe *catamount*? **;^)**

Comment: @J.R. Is that a Pinocchio nose I detect in that emoticon?

Comment: While *para-* is a common prefix, the prefix here is actually *par-*.

Comment: @Sven - Nope. **;==⊃)**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to the *American Heritage Dictionary*, the words *paramount* and *tantamount* do not share any roots:

> **paramount** [AN *paramont* : OFr. *par,* by (< Lat. *per*) + OFr. *amont,* above.]

> **tantamount** [< obs. *tantamount,* an equivalent < AN *tant amunter,* to amount to as much.]

So not only is there no trio to complete, you don't even have a duo.

Comment: You've ruined my day